# Proof of the undecidability of compiler code optimization

Tags: undecidability, compilers

While reading *Compilers* by *Alfred Aho*, I came across this statement:

> The problem of generating the
> optimal target code from a source program is undecidable in general.

The Wikipedia entry on optimizing compilers reiterates the same without a proof.

Here's my question: Is there a proof (formal or informal) of why this statement is true? If so, please provide it.

Comment: You may be interested in [this post on the generalized incompleteness theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486348/21820), where the unsolvability of simple computability problems can be used to easily prove the generalized incompleteness theorem. That is, the same easy-to-prove facts of unsolvability of the halting problem can not only be used to justify the statement you found but also to deduce Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Having worked on several compilers, I can recall numerous situations where the optimal coding was dependent on the input data.

Comment: As the answers suggest, it's not just undecidable "in general" - it's undecidable typically. It's very undecidable. Famously undecidable. To the point where you never try anything but well-established optimizing transformations.

Comment: Search Rice Theorem. Basically **any** semantic property cannot be decided for all programs. Optimizing a program basically means finding a semantic property and using that to make sure your program runs faster. The semantic property may be "this thing never happens", or "this result is always X" etc. However undecidable does not mean that you cannot analyze specific instances, it simply means you cannot write a program that works for any input.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Optimized program must have the same behavior as the original program. Consider the following program:

```
int main() {
    f();
    g();
}
```

, where it's guaranteed that $f$ is pure function. The only question is: does it finish its execution? If it does, then we can replace `main()`'s body with `g()`. Otherwise, we should replace it with an infinite loop. Unfortunately, verifying whether `f()` finishes its execution is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Another example is the program with body `print(f(42))`, where `f` is pure. The optimal program would just replace `f(42)` with its value. However, there is no algorithm that does this. We may try to compute it in compile-time, but it may never finish.

Another example (now without infinite loops). Assume that your program defines a context-free grammar and $f(x)$ checks whether string $x$ belongs to the language defined by this grammar (for any CFG we can build such $f$ automatically). Then if $f$ is a constant "true", then

```
if (f(x)) {
    g()
}
```

can be optimized to `g()`. Unfortunately, checking that grammar accepts all strings is called a universality problem and is known to be [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Universality).

Comment: Do you know if the same conclusion holds if one uses as equivalence of programs, instead of same outputs for the same inputs, to be same states for the same inputs? Although maybe for this question to make sense the details of how exactly the language in question is defined to corresponds to states of the machine and transition functions.

Comment: It's still not computable if you cook up some "uneeded infinite loop oblivious" equivalence relation. Or rather such an equivalence is not a well formed idea. Consider a program that loops until it finds a solution to an instance of hilberts 10th problem and then outputs the solution. If a solution exists then it should print out the solution but otherwise it prints out nothing. The optimal program would for a solvable instance just print the solution and print nothing when there isn't a solution. So such a compiler could solve the 10th problem but optimizing and then running the program.

Comment: @Jake My question is not well defined. But note that what you are saying in the last part is not what I am asking. An optimal program, within the equivalence class of programs that pass through the same states as the given one, would have to do more than just the same outputs. For example, if the given program passes, for a given input, through the states `testing the zero solution`, `testing solutions with absolute value <2`, `testing solutions with absolute value <4`, etc, then, in the question that I asked, the optimized program would have to do the same.

Comment: @Jake Note that being this a stronger requirement, it is, a priori, simpler to check than the equivalence of same outputs.

Comment: Ah I see. Hmm, maybe that could work? It's a good question that needs a proper formalization I think. Now that I understand what you mean a bit better I think it depends on the formalization. If we use basic blocks as "states" then I suspect the answer is still "no" because you can encode undecidable problems without control flow...if we use Turing machine states then I'm not sure this enables any optimization. Also for some definitions of this I can imagine we're not able to remove branches that don't effect the final outcome which seems important to an "optimal" optimizer.

Comment: Careful: if you consider a **fixed** CFG grammar $G$ then the problem of deciding whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$ is decidable. Indeed it must be decided by one of the following two Turing machines: 1) Accept immediately. 2) Reject immediately. If $G$ is part of the input then the problem is undecidable.

Comment: @Steven, thanks for the comment, I'll clarify this

Comment: @Steven The grammar may be fixed in the program, but the program is an input to the compiler, which must decide whether the program accepts all strings.

Comment: @user253751, Agreed! That's exactly what the subtlety is.

Comment: It looks like your example is C code. That is critically important. In C, you _can_ replace the body of `main` with `g()`. C defines the behavior of a program in terms of an abstract machine with observable behavior. Pure functions have no observable behavior.

Comment: The problem with this answer is I could come back and ask the original question again with the assumption of well-behavenedness for all programs to optimize. That is to say I guarantee the optimizer will not receive any non-terminating (unless trivial infinite loop) or undefined programs.

Comment: @Joshua In that case you would be asking a different question, which does not indicate anything wrong with this answer.

Comment: @Joshua, what's wrong with the final example? Well-defined, always terminates.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks for the comment. I didn't have this in mind:) I'm not good in this field, so I don't dare write it in the answer; if you can make a good addition to the answer, can I trouble you to edit it?

Comment: @Dmitry: I've been looking for some time for an example of an undecidable problem that doesn't depend on the halting problem.

Comment: @Joshua Then I think we can construct a halting-problem-*like* counterexample: the program runs the optimizer on itself, then does the opposite of whatever the optimizer says it does.

Comment: @Dmitry: I thought I could fix the example, but the problem is even bigger than I initially thought. The additional problem is in the "Otherwise, we should replace it with an infinite loop." idea. That loop can be removed in a subsequent optimization step, as it would remove zero observable effects. This would again leave `g()`, so it does not matter whether `f()` halts.

Answer (score 9):

For most interesting optimisations, I think this is implied by [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). For real numbers, [Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem) is also relevant here.

Comment: Also the Myhill‐Shepherdson theorem is relevant - Rice's theorem only concerns total functions, Myhill-Shepherdson plays a similar role for partial functions. (Both can be formulated quite abstractedly too, in more general settings than "functions on natural numbers".)

Answer (score 3):

With some programming languages and computation models, you could even say that **optimizing programs is the same as running them** — just with a subset of computation rules. Then, if you allow enough optimizations to happen, it is clear that optimization faces the same non-termination problems as running programs.

Let me elaborate on my claim by providing a **concrete example of a made-up language and its computational semantics**.

Consider the following source code of a very **primitive imperative language** [1].

```
i := 0;;

IF (i == 0) do:
  SKIP
;;

WHILE true do:
  i := i + (1 + 1) ;;
  i := i + 3
```

I hope the language grammar becomes clear from the above sample. It supports statements such as assignments `variable name := ...`, if conditions `IF ... do:`, while loops `WHILE ... do:`), and concatenated statements `... ;; ...`. Moreoever, it allows scalar expressions such as boolean conditions `... == ...`, `true`, `false`, and simple arithmetic like `... + 3` within some of the previous statements.

### Evaluation by Rules

Let us now invent a computational semantics for running such programs. Concretely, we will do so in terms of **small-step semantics**, i.e. a binary evaluation relation between contextual statements: we write `p,Γ ⤳ p',Γ'` if program `p` with variable states `Γ` transitions (computes, evaluates) to program `p'` with variable states `Γ'`.
Then, the interpreter for our language works as follows: upon a program `p`, it picks the default start state for variables `Γ_ini` and tries reducing it as long as possible:

> `p,Γ_ini ⤳ p',Γ' ⤳ p'',Γ'' ⤳ ... ⤳ RET`

Hopefully, this ends with a special program `RET` denoting termination. But it may very well happen that running does not terminate at all. For instance, our sample program invokes such non-terminating behavior — at least with the (intuitive) semantics we give next.

We give the following rules on statements, where `S`, `S'`, `T` are meta variables for statements, `E`, `E'` are meta variables for expressions, and `Γ` a meta variable for contexts, and all of them are implicitly all-quantified.

- if `S,Γ ⤳ S',Γ'`, then `(S ;; T),Γ ⤳ (S' ;; T),Γ'`
- always `(SKIP ;; S),Γ ⤳ S,Γ`
- if `E,Γ ⇝ E'`, then `(X := E),Γ ⤳ (X := E'),Γ`
- if `E,Γ ⇝ E'`, then `(IF E do S),Γ ⤳ (IF E' do: S),Γ`
- always `(IF true do: S),Γ ⤳ S,Γ`
- always `(IF false do: S),Γ ⤳ SKIP,Γ`
- always `(WHILE E do: S),Γ ⤳ (IF E do: S ;; WHILE E do: S),Γ`

where ⇝ is a similar small-step relation on expressions that I omit here. There, `E,Γ ⇝ E'` means that expression `E` in context `Γ` transitions to expression `E'`. Note that since expressins cannot change variable state in our language, we omit the context `Γ` on the right-hand side of ⇝.

### Optimization by Restricted Evaluation

How can we now formulate optimization rules for our language? For instance, our intuition demands that in the program above the statement `IF (i == 0) do: SKIP` optimize to nothing.
It turns out we can achieve this with the very same tool of small-step semantics. For our purposes, we give the following set of optimization rules for the optimization relation ⤅:

- if `S,Γ ⤅ S',Γ'`, then `(S ;; T),Γ ⤳ (S' ;; T),Γ'`
- if *forall* Δ, `T,Δ ⤅ T',Δ`, then `(S ;; T),Γ ⤳ (S ;; T'),Γ` (optimization does not need to be sequential as evaluation was)
- always `(IF E do: SKIP),Γ ⤅ SKIP,Γ`
- always `(SKIP ;; E),Γ ⤅ E,Γ`

With them, we see that our program above indeed first optimizes to `i := 0 ;; (SKIP ;; WHILE true do: ...)` (where I annotated parentheses explicitly) and then to `i := 0 ;; (WHILE true do: ...)` as desired.

Note that in contrast to the evaluation rules, here the exhaustive application of the optimization rules above does terminate — at least I hope this can be proven via induction. But this is just a consequence of our yet naive way of optimization. If we optimized many things further, we would also run into possibly non-terminating territory.

#### Correctness of Optimization

Importantly, **optimization rules need to be derivable from the evaluation rules** for *sane* programs, i.e. be a *subset* in some sense. Otherwise, our optimizations would be wrong. Regarding sanity, for instance our third optimization rule can only be derived *if* we assume that for `E` occurring in the if condition, we always have either `E,Γ ⇝ ... ⇝ true` or `E,Γ ⇝ ... ⇝ false`.
Moreover, our second rule is only derivable if we assume that the `S` contained therein never gets stuck. In richer languages, `S` may even throw an exception.

However, both previous assumptions do usually hold if our language is typed, our type theory ensures soundness ("well-typed programs never get stuck/throw exceptions"), and the input program for optimization is actually well-typed.
Indeed, the definitions of sanity of many programming language optimizers usually include well-typedness as a necessary condition.
The C language is a prime example for a case where sanity of programs encompasses much more than well-typedness alone: namely, many optimizations by compilers are only correct *if* the input programs do not exhibit [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

[1]: the language and its semantics are heavily inspired from the language *Imp* presented in the [*Software Foundations* series, *Volume 1: Logical Foundations*](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/lf-current/Imp.html) by Pierce, de Amorim, Casinghino, Gaboardi, Greenberg, Hriţcu, Sjöberg, Yorgey et al.

Answer (score 2):

It’s quite easy to write a program that will either print the smallest even N >= 4 which is not the sum of two primes, or run forever.

Run it through the optimiser. The optimised output would be either a program printing some long string of digits, or an empty loop. So that’s one hard mathematical problem your optimiser would have to crack.

Comment: Note that hard or currently unknown is not the same as undecidable.

Answer (score 2):

Like many undecidability results about program analysis, this is a consequence of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Consider the function $g := x \mapsto \mathsf{if} \; f(x) \; \mathsf{then} \; 0 \; \mathsf{else} \; x$ where $C$ may contain variables. An optimal optimizer must optimize calls to this function to $0$ if $f(x)$ is true for every $x$.

The property “this function evaluates to $\mathsf{true}$ regardless of the value of its argument” is a non-trivial property of partial functions, therefore in accordance to Rice's theorem there is no algorithm to decide it.

Taking the contraposite, for any correct optimizer $T$, there exists a function $f_T$ which is always true, but such that $T$ does not realize that $f_T$ is always true and therefore does not optimize calls to $g$ to $0$.

The one part of this proof that I didn't model formally above is “an optimal optimizer must optimize …”: I didn't define what it means for an optimizer to be optimal. This requires a cost model over the programming language. One possible cost model is that every function call costs $1$. In this model, replacing $g(x)$ by $0$ decreases the cost by at least 1 so an optimal optimizer must do it.

This example works with any cost model where a function application has a nonzero cost and the cost of evaluating a program is larger or equal than the cost of evaluating any subprogram that gets evaluated as part of the evaluation of the larger program. For example, any “sane” small-step semantics is of this type: calling a function is a beta reduction, and the cost of evaluating a program is the number of instances of reduction rules that get applied.